# I want full code Populate the menu from database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I Created a mvc application with database menu. I want to render the menu from when it is loading first time in the master page.

please help me..

Comment: add you code in the post for more clarification.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Comment: Are you talking about having a provider for the menu, so that you can load it according to the user and authorizations?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from you question, you need a menu which you need to render on every page. Follow these steps :

1. Create a controller action for your menu item. Something like below :

   ```
     [ChildActionOnly]
     public ActionResult sampleChildAction() {

         var model = _myMenuRepo.GetAll();
         return View(model);
     }
   ```
2. Create a view for this action. Looks something like below :

   ```
     @{
         Layout = null;
     }

     <ul>
         @foreach(var item in Model) { 
             <li>
                 <a href="@item.MyHref">@item.MyDesc</a>
             </li>
         }
     </ul>
   ```
3. Call this action from you layout. Code should look like something this :

   ```
   <div>
       <h3>Menu</h3>

       @Html.Action("sampleChildAction", 
         new { controller = "Sample" }
       )
   </div>
   ```

This article also can help you :

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

For further implementations, you might wanna consider caching this part of your application :

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/donut-hole-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-by-using-child-actions-and-outputcacheattribute